# Is there any Android mp3 player other than MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, media-player

I have searched for another mp3 player to use in my android project but i couldn't find. ***MediaPlayer*** is not good !

I'm trying to play a song , so when i click the song it plays , but if i click it again it should stop , MediaPlayer is not working good , i tried to make a
***ProgressDialog***

it also did not work .

```
viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String name = model.getTitle();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "you clicked on -> " + name , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    String url = model.getMusic();
                    
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext() , Uri.parse(url));
                    
                    mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()){
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                            mp.start();
                        }
                    });
                    if(mp.isPlaying()){
                        mp.stop();
                    }else {
                        mp.start();
                    }


                }
            });
```

Comment: hmm... [ExoPlayer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html)?

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "MediaPlayer is not working good" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare The Android regular MediaPlayer , i'm trying to make it load with progressdialog and play on the first click  , and if the song clicked again it has to stop .

Comment: I dont see where in your code are you trying to stop playback.

Comment: @Okas I have tried to stop it , i'm asking how ?

Comment: That does not explain what "is not working good" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare How do i stop it ? that is what i'm asking . I tried some ways from the internet but it did not work

Comment: "How do i stop it ?" -- call `stop()` on the `MediaPlayer`. "I tried some ways from the internet but it did not work" -- the code in your question does not show any of the "some ways" that you tried, and you have not explained what "it did not work" means. Please provide a [mcve], which in this case would be the code that "did not work" and an explanation of what "did not work" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare Here , i edited the code , that is what i tried so far

Comment: OK. So, what does "did not work" mean?

Comment: @CommonsWare When i run the App , ProgressDialog pops up and don't disappear .

Comment: In the future: ask the real question ("why does my `ProgressDialog` not disappear?" instead of "Is there any Android mp3 player other than MediaPlayer?"), provide that [mcve], and be **very detailed** in your explanation of what not is working. When you do that -- as you have now done, several comments later -- you stand a much better chance of getting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the static `create()` method. The media will be prepared before that method returns. Your `OnPreparedListener` listener will never be called in your existing code.

The simple solution is to get rid of the `OnPreparedListener` and call `dismiss()` after `create()`. Most likely, you will find that your `ProgressDialog` does not do much good.

Alternatively:

- Replace `create()` with just calling `new MediaPlayer()`
- Add your `OnPreparedListener`
- Call `setDataSource()` on the `MediaPlayer` in a background thread, as this will perform some disk I/O, and you do not want to do that on the main application thread

You may need to then arrange to call `dismiss()` on the main application thread — I have not tried to `dismiss()` a dialog from a background thread, and I do not know if that is supported.